# XCode project on Jenkins, stuck at "codesign"

Tags: ios, xcode, continuous-integration, jenkins

I use Jenkins for continuous integration with XCode plugin, there is a project that Jenkins stuck at:

/usr/bin/codesign --force --sign ......

followed by the spinner, and forever spinning, I've never seen this before, anyone seen this before? Is it a provisioning profile issue, or certificate issue? On Jenkins the provisioning profile and certificate are correctly installed and showing a green tick in Organizer, so I've no idea what can cause this issue.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Check your Mac OS machine, it should be prompting a request to access the keychain. Until you don't accept or reject the access to the keychain the job remains stuck.

Comment: Is there any way to automatically access the keychain?  It seems counter-productive to have to check the MacOS build machine in order to finish an automated build.

Comment: Have you tried http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16550594/jenkins-xcode-build-works-codesign-fails ?

Comment: This was the issue for me! New App / Certificate / Build so hadn't previously approved Jenkins to access the cert!