# building xcode project from jenkins fails. when building in command line runs just fine. why?

Tags: ios, xcode, jenkins, osx-mavericks

building xcode project from jenkins fails. 
when building in command line runs just fine. 
why?
this is is the error I get:

```
[BEROR]Code Sign error: No matching provisioning profile found: Your build settings specify a provisioning profile with the UUID ‚Äú_UUID_‚Äù, however, no such provisioning profile was found.
[BEROR]CodeSign error: code signing is required for product type 'Application' in SDK 'iOS 7.1'
```

this is the command line used:
xcodebuild -project *PROJECTNAME*.xcodeproj/ -target *TARGETNAME* -configuration Release -sdk iphoneos7.1 clean build

ps: anything with *OBJECT* was censored so this question can appear online, there was real data there before.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using the login key-chain or did you create a different key-chain for jenkins builds app signing?

If you are just using the login key-chain make sure you unlock the key-chain during the build.
If you are using a different key-chain make sure you swap key-chains and then unlock it.

[Jenkins - Xcode build works codesign fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16550594/jenkins-xcode-build-works-codesign-fails) - this thread is quite informative.

Also adding these 2 commands to your build can help you debug it:

```
/usr/bin/security list-keychains
/usr/bin/security find-identity
```