# Ad-Hoc codesigning for device succeeds in Studio, Fails in Jenkins

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, jenkins, xamarin.ios

I have a Xamarin Forms application that supports Android and iOS.  I've generated Jenkins builds to compile them.  All of the Android builds work.  The iOS Debug build compiles fine.  The Ad-Hoc build, however, fails to build completely for an iPhone target.  It appears to be failing during codesigning.  It works if I target the iPhoneSimulator, but if I target iPhone device it fails.

> Tool /usr/bin/codesign execution started with arguments: -v --force --sign 81088F8E194139DC4C6CE640716944E41FB0709F --entitlements "/Users/Shared/Jenkins/.jenkins/workspace/{project path}/obj/iPhone/Ad-Hoc/Entitlements.xcent" --deep "/Users/Shared/Jenkins/.jenkins/workspace/{project path}/bin/iPhone/Ad-Hoc/AppName.app"
>   bin/iPhone/Ad-Hoc/AppName.app : error : /Users/Shared/Jenkins/.jenkins/workspace/{project path}/bin/iPhone/Ad-Hoc/AppName.app: unknown error -1=ffffffffffffffff [/Users/Shared/Jenkins/.jenkins/workspace/{project path}/iDriverMobile.iOS.csproj]

If I open up the Solution in Visual Studio, right in the Jenkins workspace folder so it's using the exact same files, then compilations works fine, which is really frustrating.

Looking at differences between the two outputs, it seems that the working build (from Studio) has AOT output for all of the assemblies that looks like this:

> Mono Ahead of Time compiler - compiling assembly /Users/Shared/Jenkins/.jenkins/workspace/{project path}/obj/iPhone/Ad-Hoc/mtouch-cache/32/Build/OpenNETCF.Google.Analytics.dll

The failing build has none of those.  Instead, it has a couple lines that look like this:

> MTOUCH : warning MT0095: Aot files could not be copied to the destination directory /Users/Shared/Jenkins/.jenkins/workspace/{project path}/obj/iPhone/Ad-Hoc/mtouch-cache/64/Build/Msym/Msym/tmp: Could not start process. [/Users/Shared/Jenkins/.jenkins/workspace/{project path}/AppName.csproj]

The worst part of all of this is that these builds did work, but then I restarted the Mac Mini that Jenkins is running on and things went downhill.  I can't figure out what the difference is between what Studio is doing and the command line call to msbuild.  They both point to the same binaries.

**Additional Information**
This still fails with the latest updates as of today (5/24/17).  This is the environment:

- Mac OS X 10.12.5
- List item
- XCode 8.3.2
- Xamarin.iOS 10.10.0.36
- Visual Studio 2017 Community for Mac 7.0.1 (build 24)
- Mono 5.0.1.1

What *doesn't* fix it:

- Creating a new Jenkins build
- Changing the Jenkins workspace path
- Opening up permissions (777) to the entire Jenkins folder
- Enabling LLVM
- Disabling all linking
- Completely uninstalling and re-installing Jenkins
- Using `xbuild` instead of `msbuild`
- Swearing a lot
- My middle finger

Comment: I assume you already got through something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19550453/2054072) and the unlocking given you're saying the keychain is accessible, but did you had a look at [this](https://github.com/Carthage/Carthage/issues/782#issuecomment-163007154) too? You might be signing the app twice resulting in the error you're experiencing

Comment: Did you check file and folder permissions for the jenkins user? You said this started happening after a restart - maybe when jenkins is run as a daemon it doesn't have enough permissions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to delete the derived data folder in `DerivedData` of your app. It looks like `YourAPP_ dasfdsfsdafdsasfdsaf`, according to [this](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/64101) from Apple Developer Forum.

The `DerivedData` data folder is located at `~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/`

If this does not work, all the symptoms point to a signing certificate (also called, signing identity) issue.

It seems like when it was compiled from command line, `/usr/bin/codesign` can not access signing identity `81088F8E194139DC4C6CE640716944E41FB0709F`. It could be many different reasons, unfortunately:

- keychain was locked
- `codesign` is not allowed to access the signing
  identity.
- multiple identities exist in keychain and wrong signing
  identity was selected
- Wrong provision
  profile was matched for Ad Hoc build.

Try to add following code snippets before running `msbuild`, assuming your signing identity is in keychain `~/Library/Keychains/login.keychain`:

```
security unlock-keychain -p <password> ~/Library/Keychains/login.keychain
security set-keychain-settings -l -u -t 3600 ~/Library/Keychains/login.keychain
security set-key-partition-list -S apple-tool:,apple:,codesign: -s -k -p <password> ~/Library/Keychains/login.keychain
```

It is not a good idea to have keychain password stored in the build script, you can follow [this guide](https://support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/203802500-Injecting-Secrets-into-Jenkins-Build-Jobs) to hide them.