# Codesign returns unknown error after "replacing existing signature"

Tags: ios, xamarin, msbuild, codesign, xbuild

I am trying to build a Xamarin iOS app using xbuild on Jenkins. Sometimes the build fails during the codesigning process with an *unknown error -1=ffffffffffffffff* and sometimes the build succeeds. The provisioning profile is stored in a separate keychain *jenkins.keychain* (not the system or login keychain) that is referenced by Jenkins through the [Keychains and Provisioning Profiles Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Keychains+and+Provisioning+Profiles+Plugin).

This is the console log of Jenkins:

```
Target _CodesignAppBundle:
    Codesign Task
      CodesignAllocate: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/codesign_allocate
      DisableTimestamp: False
      Entitlements: obj/iPhone/In-House/Entitlements.xcent
      Keychain: <null>
      Resources:
        bin/iPhone/In-House/MyApp.app
      ResourceRules: <null>
      SigningKey: 123
      ExtraArgs: <null>
      IsAppExtension: False
    Tool /usr/bin/codesign execution started with arguments: -v --force --sign 123 --entitlements /private/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Master/Apps/iOS/obj/iPhone/In-House/Entitlements.xcent /private/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Master/Apps/iOS/bin/iPhone/In-House/MyApp.app


bin/iPhone/In-House/MyApp.app: error : /private/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Master/Apps/iOS/bin/iPhone/In-House/MyApp.app: replacing existing signature
   /private/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Master/Apps/iOS/bin/iPhone/In-House/MyApp.app: unknown error -1=ffffffffffffffff
    Task "Codesign" execution -- FAILED
    Done building target "_CodesignAppBundle" in project "/private/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Master/Apps/iOS/MyApp.csproj".-- FAILED
```

As suggested in [Codesign returned unknown error -1=ffffffffffffffff](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44173831/codesign-returned-unknown-error-1-ffffffffffffffff) I added `set-key-partition-list -S apple-tool:,apple:,codesign: -s -k ${KEYCHAIN_PW} ${KEYCHAIN_PATH}` to my build script but it did not fix the issue.

Do you have any idea how to address this issue? Why is there an existing signature to be replaced?

**Update 1 - We keep getting the error after:**

- switching from `xbuild` to `msbuild` version 15.3.0.0
- setting jenkins keychain to ["Allow all applications to access this item"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43157573/4739420)
- deleting the [derived data folder](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44307605/4739420)
- not using relative paths for [`security` commands](https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/issues/8797)

A similar problem is described in the [Apple forum](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/64101).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**What fixed the issue:**

The keychain filename extension changed from **.keychain* to **.keychain-db* on macOS Sierra. The code signing error was caused by referencing the old keychain file while we were editing in fact the *jenkins.keychain-db* file containing updated certificates. [Keychains with the new extension are rejected from the upload with Jenkins' keychain plugin](https://github.com/SICSoftwareGmbH/kpp-management-plugin/issues/5). So we do not use the keychain plugin any longer and store the signing certificates inside the *login.keychain-db*. With this we can successfully build the app without the *unknown error*.

Answer (score 1):

My resolution to this problem was ensuring that the Mac had proper permissions to use the new certificate.  I was getting this code signing issue when trying to run a Jenkins job, but things ran properly on my local machine.  When I tried manually code signing one of the Swift libraries (e.g. `libswiftos.dylib`), the Mac then asked for a password to be able to use the new certificate.  Once I did that, the Jenkins job ran successfully.

Answer (score -1):

Restarting the Mac could Fix the issue