# "replace existing signature" error when deploying

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I receive the error "replace existing signature" when trying to deploy an app to a device or simulator.

Strangely, it doesn't do it every time. It will build ok a few times and then the error will arise. If I rebuild the app, then the error goes away briefly.

How can a situation such as this arise?

Comment: Did you try delete the obj/bin folder and the rebuild the project?

Comment: Yes I've tried that.

Answer (score 2):

The issue comes whenever you have multiple certificates and provisioning profiles installed so the automatic signing that you have selected won't know which profile to use. There are [suggestions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46111418/xamarin-forms-ios-error-replacing-existing-signature) to do a lot, but I would suggest:

1. Open Visual Studio, into the iOS Project settings->iOS Bundle Signing and switch over to Manual selection of Provisioning profiles. Quit, Rebuild.
2. If that doesn't work, just log in your Apple Developer account and deleting and revoking all certificates/provisioning profiles in your Apple Developer and Mac that are old. Quit, Rebuild.
3. If neither works, then follow the suggestions in the link.

Comment: I've tried emptying XCode's provisions folder and reinstalling but the error keeps occurring. It's strange that a rebuild always fixed the problem, albeit briefly.

Comment: Strange, did Selecting the manual provisioning option not work either??

Comment: It doesn't appear to fix the issue.

Comment: Hmm could you provide a more detailed application output log in the question?