# Visual Studio Remove old Provisioning Profiles

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.ios, keychain, provisioning-profile

I am a little bit lost with this topic and can't explain myself this odd behavior.
On the Mac I deleted all provisioning profiles under `~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning\ Profiles`. As well I deleted all certificates in the keychain. For some reason I still have my old provisioning profile showing up in Visual Studio (Windows):

[image]

Can someone explain this behavior or tell me how to get rid of this profile?

Comment: Delete the folder bin and obj in your project and restart the IDE .

Comment: In the project folder for iOS or the main project folder?

Comment: Usually restarting the computer and restarting Visual Studio will refresh that list from the Mac build machine. Are you sure you are connecting to the right Mac?

Comment: I haven’t restarted my computer in a while so I will give it a shot. Thanks

Comment: Make sure that the version of IDE is up to date.If the problem still exists, you could report it : **Help -> Send Feedback -> Report a problem** .

Comment: VS is up to date on both Windows and my Mac. Thanks, I will probably do that. There is no GitHub page for Visual Studio where you can open an issue right?

Comment: You could check it fromhttps://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/8/index.html .

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try deleting all mobileprovision files in "%LOCALAPPDATA%\Xamarin\iOS\Provisioning\Profiles".

Comment: Perfect!!!! I actually deleted the entire folder under: `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Xamarin\iOS\Provisioning`

Comment: How do you do this for Visual Studio 4 Mac

Answer (score -2):

Restarting Visual Studio or your Windows computer will usually cause new provisioning profile and certificate information to show up.

Comment: It didn't work... For some reason it keeps showing old provisioning profiles.

Comment: Did u solve this @TomelSafadi I am having exact same issue in new build as of today

Comment: Look at the answer from Michael. Delete the files under `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Xamarin\iOS\Provisioning\Profiles`

Comment: Make sure to save the folder before though otherwise you might end up reinstalling Xamarin tools @rogue39nin