# CI failing on codesign with errSecInternalComponent (Buildkite)

Tags: ios, macos, continuous-integration, certificate, provisioning-profile

**Environment**

Hi I am using buildkite on my aws mac1.metal instances. These agents acts as CI agents in our org.  Instances now launch buildkite-agent when the instance is booted (done vis plist in /Library/LauchDaemon). Here is my [plist](https://gist.github.com/OliverKoo/c0df8b7295ab55b042a99ff4ea3eb077)

**Issue**

The agent trys to run the following command using python subprocess

```
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['/usr/bin/codesign', '-v', '--sign', 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX', '--entitlements', 'bazel-out/darwin-opt/bin/MYORG/iOS/WidgetExtension/WidgetExtension_entitlements.entitlements', '--force', 'bazel-out/darwin-opt/bin/MYORG/iOS/WidgetExtension/WidgetExtension_archive-root/WidgetExtension.appex']
```

resulting this error:

```
ERROR:
--
  | bazel-out/darwin-opt/bin/MYORG/iOS/WidgetExtension/WidgetExtension_archive-root/WidgetExtension.appex: errSecInternalComponent
```

Interestingly running the same job with agent that I launch locally. (ssh into the machine, then run `buildkite-agent start`) then it worked flawlessly. So I am wondering if there are some kind of permission difference between launching buildkite-agent as a daemon via launchd and starting it locally. (similar to this [issue](https://github.com/buildkite/agent/issues/1400) I opened before where bk agent failed a job as launchd daemon but succeed if launch locally)

**Things I have tried to fix/Debugging**

- [errSecInternalComponent seems like a common issue with codesign](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24023639/xcode-command-usr-bin-codesign-failed-with-exit-code-1-errsecinternalcomponen) so I tried locking and unlocking the keychain with `security unlock-keychain -p password path/to/key`
- people who use other CI system/tool also encounter the same issue but largely [solve when setting `SessionCreate` in their plist.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6827874/missing-certificates-and-keys-in-the-keychain-while-using-jenkins-hudson-as-cont/9482707#9482707) . Tried but still failing
- VNC into the mac1.metal ec2 instance and gave /usr/local/bin/buildkite-agent FDA - still failed the job
- VNC in and open KeyChain access and give /usr/local/bin/buildkite-agent access to the private key it is having issue signing - still failed
- everything [here](https://medium.com/@ceyhunkeklik/how-to-fix-ios-application-code-signing-error-4818bd331327)
- [Jenkins - Xcode build works codesign fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16550594/jenkins-xcode-build-works-codesign-fails)
  creating a temp key in post checkout hook but still failed

Wondering if any codesign/security/buildkite wizard ‍♀️ ‍♂️ out there knows the difference between launchd buildkite-agent and agent launch locally? I feel like there is a big gotcha I am missing. Perhaps an attribute missing in my plist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into this problem before, you need to run buildkite agent as LaunchAgent and configure auto login, instead of run as LaunchDaemon.